# how to retrieve which child view has been selected previous in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and setting BaseAdapter for it,the row layout has only textview.

I am keeping track of the previous textview by having view object, now when I scroll the listview view, previoustextview obj is not working.

How to know which child view has been selected previously.

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView txtview = (TextView) convertView;            
        boolean flag = false;
        final Resources res = getResources();
        final Drawable actbtnDoneDraw = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.action_done_button);
        final Drawable actbtnSelectedDraw = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.action_button_selected);
        final Drawable actbtnDraw = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.action_button);

        if (null == convertView) {

                if (DeviceDetail.isGalaxyTabOriginal()) {
                    txtview = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_txtview_gtab0, parent,
                            true);
                } else {

                    txtview = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_txtview, parent, false);

                }

            } else {
                txtview = (TextView) convertView;
                if (selectedposition != position) {
                    txtview.setBackgroundDrawable(actbtnDraw);
                    txtview.setSelected(false);

                } else {

                    txtview.setBackgroundDrawable(actbtnSelectedDraw);
                    txtview.setSelected(true);

                }
            }
            final Activity activity = activities.get(position);
            txtview.setText(activity.name);
            txtview.setTag(Integer.valueOf(activity.id));

            txtview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    selectedposition = position;
                    Log.i("Onclick position = " + position);
                    modifyButtonView(v, position);
                }
            });

        }

public void modifyButtonView(final View view, final int position) {

        final TextView v = (TextView) view;
        final TextView pv = (TextView) previousview;

        final Resources res = getResources();
        final Drawable actbtnSelectedDraw = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.action_button_selected);
        final Drawable actbtnDraw = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.action_button);



        if (NoSelection) {
            v.setSelected(true);
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(actbtnSelectedDraw);


        } else {
            if (previousposition != position) {

                v.setSelected(true);
                pv.setBackgroundDrawable(actbtnDraw);
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(actbtnSelectedDraw);
                pv.setSelected(false);
            }
        }            

        previousview = v;
        previousposition = position;
        NoSelection = false;
        mListener.onActivityButtonClicked(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// getting the previous view, depending on the position,....  method(view,position)

```
            final int wantedPosition = previousposition;
            final int firstPosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition()
                    - listview.getHeaderViewsCount();
            final int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;
            if (!(wantedChild > firstPosition && wantedPosition < listview
                    .getLastVisiblePosition())) {
```

// incase if you have textview only in as a row view than

```
                pv = (TextView) listview.getChildAt(wantedChild);
                if (pv == null) {
                    pv = (TextView) previousview;
                }
            }
            if (previousposition != position) {
                // perform the operation on the pv view or current v view
            }
        }
        previousview = v;
        previousposition = position;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to know which child view has been selected previously.

Add two field variables to your Adapter class, call them `public int previousChoice` and `currentChoice`. Inside your `onItemClick()` or `onListItemClick()` method update this value with the third parameter  `position`.

```
mAdapter.previousChoice = mAdapter.currentChoice;
mAdapter.currentChoice = position;
```

Comment: All right, i want to modify drawablebackground of that child view.. how can i do ..? my ultimate goal is to modify previouschild view...

Comment: You will need to modify `getView()` to change the background effectively, post the code that you are using.

Comment: Click ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14047236/edit) in your question to add the code there.

Comment: It was not allowing me to answer my own question, so I have edited my original question.

Comment: So what backgrounds do you want for the current row, previous row, and all other rows?

Comment: initally blue (actbtndraw), after selection/clicking green (actbtnselecteddraw)... my idea is when user click on row/textview it turns green/ and if it click another one previous one turns back to original blue...

Comment: Ok, I thought you wanted the current selection one color and the previous one another and a third default color. But you only want two colors. Does the code you posted do what you want?

Comment: yes does, it changes the color, but if i scroll down and select last item, again i scroll up and back down now i select second last, so it changes to green, not the last item changes back to blue.

Comment: Oh, you are using `previousposition` in one method and `selectedposition` in the other. You need to change one of these.

Comment: @Bhaumik, be sure, with the `convertView`, to set a default background drawable when it isn't the previous child view, otherwise you'll find that more views will have that special background as the view gets reused.